# How can I show that the given series diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> How can I show that this series diverges?
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\bigl(2 + (-1)^n\bigr)^n}{\sqrt{n}\,3^n}
> $$

The standard tests kinda fail in this case. I am not getting any clue on how to proceed. How can I use the partial sum-boundedness to prove it or the $n$th partial sum?

Comment: I edited your question to typset the series. Please peruse [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to use LaTeX/MathJax markup.

Comment: If this sum did converge, it would have to be absolutely convergent since all terms are non negative. So, break sum into even/odd terms, and you'll see that the sum of the odd terms converges while the sum of the even terms diverge. Can you finish?

Comment: @MatthewH. How should I split it? Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $n \geq 1$, let  $u_n = \dfrac{\bigl(2 + (-1)^n\bigr)^n}{\sqrt{n}\,3^n}$.

Then one has
$$u_{2n} = \dfrac{3^{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}3^{2n} }= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$$

and $$u_{2n+1} = \dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{2n+1})3^{2n+1}}$$

Now it is easy to see that the series $\displaystyle \sum u_{2n}$ diverges whereas the series $\displaystyle \sum u_{2n+1}$ converges, and hence, by sum, the series $\displaystyle \sum u_{n}$ diverges.